# Can I assign a identifier to my button so I can know which button's constraint is wrong in console

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I am making a custom keyboard in xib, and the buttons' constraints are added and everything works fine. But in the console it says "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.". And like "UIButton:0x7f8a38411b50.leading" and so on. But there are too many buttons here, I just don't know which button the console it talks about. Can I assign a identifier to button so I can know which button's constraint need to be fixed? By the way it's in a custom keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For the app:**
You can use the View Debugger in the Xcode.
For information on the View Debugger you can go through the following link:
[View Debugger Documentation by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html)

**For the Keyboard Extension:**
Write a category on UIButton and override the method: `- (NSString *)description;`
You can do something like this in your View Controller:

```
@implementation UIButton (ButtonDesc)

- (NSString *)description
{
    return self.titleLabel.text;
}

@end
```

Here, I'm returning the text of the button. You can return a string that is made up of unique information like tag, background color, etc which will help you in identifying the particular button.
You might know where exactly the constraints are breaking. Put a break point there and write something like this in the console:

```
po 0x78f45ab0
```

where 0x78f45ab0 is the address of the button.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention I am making a custom keyboard extension. View debugger seems not working in it.

Comment: This is much simpler. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the property of `UIButton` which is call `tag`.

Comment: Will the tag display in the console?

Comment: but I didn't find the tag in the console.

Comment: Are you using lldb to debug?

Comment: @yongho To log, try `p self.button.tag`.

Comment: I think you misread my question. I am not debugging a button. When I run the app in simulator, the Xcode console prints some logs about my buttons constraint has problem, but I have no idea which button it is referring to.

Comment: Please try to understand my question first.

Comment: @yongho Oh, what I mean is you can put all the buttons you had set up into a array using tag, then print it, by comparing their address in memory, you can figure out which one is you need. My english is poor, hope you understand it.

Comment: You mean put all buttons in a array, each button assign a tag to it. Then I po this array, then comparing the address?